# Migration of mail from Ubuntu Server to Google Apps

Tags: server

As I'm no longer able to keep my pet server around, I've migrated my e-mail chores to a Google Apps domain. But I'd rather keep my old e-mail archive around. I've tried hacking it by connecting Evolution to both accounts and drag-dropping between the two, but the timestamps get all weird and sent mail doesn't show up correctly.

While there is a [Mail Migration API](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/email_migration/developers_guide_protocol.html), that doesn't work with the Standard Edition accounts, so no luck there.

Any alternative ways of moving my e-mail? Preferably something that works from the Server, but I'm willing to take detours, as it is a one-time job.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do migrations between IMAP servers is to copy your mail using an IMAP client.  You can do that using a normal mail client, but I suggest you use a more specialized tool like `imapsync` or `imapcopy` (install using `apt-get` or from Software Center).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using imap on your server at the moment it may be possible to use http://migrationtool.sourceforge.net/ to do the migration through imap.

I haven't used it myself so can't vouch for whether it's any good. The imap route seems the most obvious way to go though.

Answer (score 0):

I have made recently migration from zimbra server (on ubuntu) to google apps.
We did it in two ways depending account.

One and easies way were to make google apps to download posts using pop from original server (and leave messages there tho...)
  Couple hints, make new address or use other one from google apps (example for mail test.domain make new a record to original mail server like old.test.domain) and for original mail server make new alias for that accaount for old.test.domain.

2nd way (to get all those folders etc...) was to use email client (thunderbird or evolution) to drag them. Those date's didn't exactly go wrong. if you continue to use some email client you see dates correctly but it is google's webclient witch shows you date of transfer even if it knows when it was actually sent/received.

Comment: for #1 go on google apps webmail client settings->Accounts and from "Get mail from other accounts:" add new one...